# OpenCV ORB descriptor: TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'Feature2D' or its derivative)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I followed this simple [OpenCV Feature Matching example](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html) exactly:

```python
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('box.png',0) # queryImage
orb = cv2.ORB()               # Initiate ORB detector

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
```

and have been getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'Feature2D' or its derivative)
```

I'm using OpenCV 3.3.1

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is a OpenCV version compatibility issue.  Just use `cv2.ORB_create()` instead of `cv2.ORB()`.

The code should look like:

```python
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('box.png',0) # queryImage
orb = cv2.ORB_create()        # Initiate SIFT detector

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
```

Answer (score 6):

`cv2.ORB_create()`
will do the job I think

Comment: please format your code if you are going to duplicate an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note the python structures change "frequently" (in internet history years anyway). It's a good idea to pay attention to version.

Go here to find the right link: https://docs.opencv.org/

3.1.1 --> 3.1.0 --> https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/ ( OpenCV-Python Tutorials --> https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html ) ... not as pretty as that (old) readthedocs site, but more accurate. :)